# target does not exist when use docker-maven-plugin to build docker image

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven

when i use docker-maven-plugin to build docker image , it fails

ERROR:Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:1.0.0:build (default-cli) on project spring-boot-basic: Exception caught: basedir /root/workSpace/spring-boot-basic/spring-boot-basic-web/target does not exist

this is some code of pom.xml

```
<!-- docker plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <!-- docker config -->
            <configuration>
                <!-- image name -->
                <imageName>${project.build.finalName}</imageName>
                <!-- image tag -->
                <imageTags>
                    <imageTag>${project.version}</imageTag>
                </imageTags>
                <dockerDirectory>${project.basedir}</dockerDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/${jar.real.path}/target</directory>
                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

this is my project structure

```
spring-boot-basic
Dockerfile
module----spring-boot-basic-web
          src/main--------MainApp.java 
pom.xml
```

target will build in spring-boot-basic-web(module)

but when i run the 'mvn clean package' , it builds success and generates the target folder

then i run 'mvn clean package docker:build' , it builds docker image success but the error still happened

How can i do to solve the error ?

Answer (score 1):

now i know why cause the problem that i config the maven docker plugin in the parent pom which package type is 'pom' not 'jar' so when i build the project the problem occurs. 
so i put the maven docker config in the module 'spring-boot-basic-web' and then build success.